# Add Button to Menu Item with CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, button, menu, menuitem

I have a menu and I want the last menu item to be a red button. I want it to look like this [image] (and if possible with no gap on top between menu and the blue line)

but is like this:
[image]
My problem is that when I change the top padding/margin I can not align the text of this item with the rest of the menu items. 
This is the code I'm using:

```
.fusion-main-menu .fusion-last-menu-item a{
    background:#FE6C59;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-right:5px;
    padding-left:5px;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    height:60px;
    }
```

I keep experimenting with margins,paddings and height but can't get it to the form I want it. Could you help me? The site is: [tfs-sl.com](http://tfs-sl.com)

Comment: The CSS of the button alone is not enough. You need to provide a working example.

Comment: http://tfs-sl.com This is the site

Comment: First off, there's no menu on tfs-sl.com if you are not logged in. Secondly, you should recreate your problem here or on any snippet website as after we help you fix the problem nobody will be able to see the initial problem when looking at your website, and your question will lose its teaching value for future users. These are the rules/principles of SO, everyone is expected to respect them.

Comment: I'm sorry that I forgot it on maintenance, you can check the site again.
How could I recreate the problem here? I thought it was ok because of the images I added, I didn't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the link there is a `span` element. Put your styling on that one:

```
.fusion-main-menu .fusion-last-menu-item a span {
  background:#FE6C59;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding:4px;
  }
```

Comment: Yes! It worked actually. I added the styling options to the span element as you suggested. Thank you very much!